# What is role of hidden field value in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using hidden type form value in `HTML`. how we connect this with `javascript` and `jquery`. 
I tried this:

**HTML :**

```
<label>Company Name:</label><br />
<input type="text" name="21602-0" id="21602-0" size="30" value="<%= FormValues["21602-0"] % />
```

**JS:**

```
vars[1] != null ? $('#21620-' + index.toString()).val(vars[1]) : $('#21620-' + index.toString()).val('');
```

Comment: What exactly is the question/issue?

Comment: how i am pass hidden form value using javascript

Comment: Hidden fields are referenced the same as those that are visible (at least from my experience). Sounds like you need a good book on web development

Comment: the code provided is not enough to explain the problem or the desired solution.

Comment: You want to access the asp.net hidden field through javascript or jquery , is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hidden fields are those fields as their name suggest which are not visible on UI (but available in source html), you can maintain state of some element using these field.

Now to access these field by name using jQuery try:

```
var text = $('[name="ElementNameHere"]').val();
```

and to set field value:

```
$('[name="ElementNameHere"]').val('new Text');
```

and using JavaScript:

```
var text = document.getElementsByName('ElementNameHere').value;
//or set new text
document.getElementsByName('ElementNameHere').value= 'new text';
```